# multiply list of row with one column by condition (DATA FRAME)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, multiplication

I want to multiply a list of columns with one col so I have list of the columns = cols and but I want to multiply only rows that
name=="A" .with the columns "multi"

```
data={"col1":[2,3,4,5],
"col2":[4,2,4,6],
"col3":[7,6,9,11],
"col4":[14,11,22,8],
"name":["A","A","V","A"],
"multi":[1.4,2.5,1.6,2.2]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
cols=list(df.columns)
for x in ["multi","name","col4"]:
    cols.remove(x)
df
```

Something like this

```
df[cols]=df.loc[df["name"]=="A"]*df["multi"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
df.loc[df.name=='A', cols] = df[df.name=='A'].apply(lambda r:r[cols]*r['multi'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
m = ~df.columns.isin(["multi","name","col4"])
df.loc[df.name=='A', m] = (df.loc[df.name=='A', m].mul(df.multi, axis=0))
df
Out[94]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4 name  multi
0   2.8   5.6   9.8    14    A    1.4
1   7.5   5.0  15.0    11    A    2.5
2   4.0   4.0   9.0    22    V    1.6
3  11.0  13.2  24.2     8    A    2.2
```